# VBscript to run a command and show output in variable

Tags: vbscript

i'm trying to create a vbscript that will run command and show output as message. 
but i'm getting error.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objScriptExec = objShell.Exec("for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %i  in ('netsh interface ip show config name^="Wi-Fi" ^| findstr "IP Address"') do echo %i")
strIpConfig = objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll
WScript.Echo strIpConfig
```

This is what I have and I keep getting error code 800A03EE when I try to run it.

[image: Please see error inbelow image link]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should escape the double quotes and start with `cmd /c` before the loop for

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objScriptExec = objShell.Exec("cmd /c for /f ""tokens=3 delims=: "" %i in ('netsh interface ip show config name^=""Wi-Fi"" ^| findstr ""IP Address""') do echo %i")
strIpConfig = objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll
WScript.Echo strIpConfig
```

Comment: HI Hackoo. I need one more help with vbscript. i want to post data from vbscript . could you please help me with that?